# Make Method Call itself using "Dot"

Tags: c#

I have have a Class called A and inside the class i put method B. Everytime b is called i want to add something to the Array.

Example

```
 class A
    {
        List<String> mParams =  new List<String>();
        void b(String param)
        {
            mParams.Add(param);
        }
    }
```

is that possible to make it like this

```
 A.b("1").b("2").b("3");
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `void` can't be chained.

Comment: In order to "chain" calls, `b()` should return the object itself, ie `return this;`

Comment: That's a *bad* syntax for this problem though. If you want to add a range of values, just ... add a range of values, ie pass an `IEnumerable<string>`. That's how the `AddRange()` methods in most containers work. This way you could write `b(new[]{"1","2","3"})` or use a list/array/container generated by some other code

Comment: Of course It should the code above just a Simple code but in some case i need to using chain method. Really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "Need to use chain method". I'd beg to differ that you _need_ to, but whatever works for you, I guess. :-)

Comment: Nowadays, this is often called a `fluent interface`.

Comment: @TEK i am not sure if i am on the right track. what i want to do is just clean my prev project sql code  "select * from user left Join Administrator" with something like a.leftJoin("User","On 1=1").leftJoin("Admin","on 2=2")..
i can't think of anything else. Maybe you got better Approach... Sorry my English.. Btw Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your method b return `this`.

```
public A b(string a)
{
    //Do stuff
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Its worked 
Clovis Portron,Panagiotis Kanavos 36  and david L